# Is there a way to insert a single character and then exit insert mode?

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

When I'm going through text and, for instance, adding backticks around certain words or quotes or whatever, it is irritating that I have to press Esc or Ctrl-[ after each insert.  The inserts (and appends) are different, so `.` doesn't help much.

Is there anything similar to `r` that returns to normal mode after a single character—but uses insert mode instead of replace mode?

Comment: You should perhaps consider using (or extending) the [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin, in order to work on the text in a more *meaningful* way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there isn't (I haven't looked), you can use this mapping in your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <C-I> i <ESC>r
```

It `i`nserts, places a space, `ESC`apes, and starts a single letter `r`eplace. This gets mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

It's a hack, and will leave a hanging space if you hit escape before you type a letter - but it's better than nothing!

Comment: Not bad...I'll probably use that if no one comes up with anything better.  :)

Comment: @Wildcard I didn't realize how much I actually run into this use case without realizing it. Good question :) I've added it to my own vimrc as well.

Comment: I spent most of the day fixing a bunch of markdown.  Italics, inline code, header indentations, hyperlinks...all of them one character inserts.  :)  Actually your solution is perfect; I'm going to start using it now.

Comment: Disadvantage: It's not repeatable with the `.` command.  :(

Comment: @Wildcard unfortunately, after doing a bit of research, there isn't a way to create a manual repeat branch for `.` unless you're using [`repeat.vim`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat).

Answer (score 0):

To insert a char at the end of a word (instead of at the cursor position), use

```
nnoremap <C-a> a <ESC>r
```

This maps to `Ctrl + a`, you can map it to anything else of course.

I have the two in my `.vimrc` just so I don't hustle much :)

```
" Insert char at cursor position
nnoremap <C-i> i <ESC>r
" Append char after cursor position
nnoremap <C-a> a <ESC>r
```